# On the Nature of Truth

Tags: logic, truth, contemporary-philosophy

I'm fairly new to philosophical readings- that is, I've only parsed through various textbooks of antiquity. My questions, regarding the nature of truth, is as follows:

Is contemporary consensus that truth is a substantive of corroborative property?
Is the notion of truth-valuelessness accepted among contemporary philosophers, or is bivalence generally perceived as incontrovertible dogma?

i.e. is it thought that truth is a disjoint metaphysical entity existing outside of thought? Or is it so that truth is simply a semantic notion that corroborates propositions (or sentences, depending on specified the truth theory).

Comment: I think the simplest answer is that there is not a contemporary consensus on what I take to be your question. The majority position is probably that truth is a property of statements or propositions and not things themselves. But then as to how that sort of truth relates to reality there is much disagreement.

Comment: @virmaior What is the consensus of a structural isomorphism between fact and true proposition?

Comment: Can you rephrase that?

Comment: @virmaior I believe it was Wittgenstein who said that there is a structural isomorhpism between names and objects, elementary propositions and states of affairs, and, propositions and facts, respectively.

Comment: How is that a rephrasing of a question?

Comment: @virmaior It is not. It is an additional question.

Comment: Actually it is not even a question

Comment: @virmaior I mistated my question. What is the contemporary consensus *on the validity* of Wittgenstein's theory?

Comment: @AnthonyPeter - I think that, if with W's theory of truth you are referecing to the Tractatus, we can conclude that it is an oversimplification, not capable of explicating the complex issue of truth. About "modern" views, you can see in *SEP* all the entries about [Truth](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth/)

Comment: As always, be careful with what you put before and after any use of "i.e.".  Truth being substantive seems to be a conceptually distinct quality to truth being mind-independent!

Comment: @Paul Ross could you elaborate on this?

Comment: @AnthonyPeter Sure; questions of substance appear to involve dependence (or supervenience, if you prefer) of a more general kind than that which we might want to use to account for mental content.  It's one thing to say that Truth depends on *something*, and another to say that it depends on a cognitive process or brain state.

Answer (score 4):

Contemporary Consensus is hard to come by in Truth given its broad interest, but the philosophical literature around it is very much motivated by Paradox phenomena following from truth as a component of language.  If Truth is taken to have a semantic character, such that it indicates a "real" property in a baseline metaphysics, then we might read proposed strategies for avoiding paradox as an attempt to give a more refined definition of this property.  If Truth is more syntactic, such as conceptions of it as a system or algebra of those sentences which we might reasonably call True, then we can read paradox resolution projects as characterising these systems through a combination of axioms and inference rules, which may or may not point to any "real" metaphysical property.

In any case, I think it's accurate to note that the question of the substantial nature of Truth is in some sense treated as an afterthought to the current philosophical work being done.  The richness of theories of Truth in contemporary treatment is very much **mathematical**, following on from papers by Alfred Tarski [[1]](http://www.cs.uwyo.edu/~jlc/courses/comp-sem/Semantic%20Conception%20of%20Truth.pdf), Saul Kripke [[2]](http://philo.ruc.edu.cn/logic/reading/Kripke_%20Theory%20of%20Truth.pdf) and others, where we take it that the mathematics used to frame the theory may or may not be suitable to a given metaphysical framework but this shouldn't hold us back from exploring the theories in abstraction.

Kripke's work is of particular relevance to your question of whether Bivalence is a central property of Truth, in that while the technology he introduces is widely accepted as a valuable extension of Tarski's work, some philosophers have read his strategy as an endorsement of the existence of truth value gaps, and others as simply an indication of the structure of an axiomatic theory of "the True sentences" which is itself a classical theory, and developed/argued against it accordingly.

In addition to SEP links by Lukas and Mauro above, I'll also add the (recently revised) SEP article for [Axiomatic Theories of Truth](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-axiomatic/) by Volker Halbach and Graham Leigh, discussing one of the big avenues for contemporary developments.

Answer (score 2):

**Is the notion of truth-valuelessness accepted among contemporary philosophers, or is bivalence generally perceived as incontrovertible dogma?**

No, there are various papers on truthvalue gaps, and a section about logics with more than two truthvalues can be found here: [SEP Truth Values](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-values/). To name but one example, Graham Priest in his 'In Contradiction' argues against truth value gaps, see chapter 1.3.

**is it thought that truth is a disjoint metaphysical entity existing outside of thought?**

There isn't really any agreement. The introductory books, judged form my personal experience, take truth to be a property of proposistion/sentences/utterances. For more on this debate though, see the SEP article again, sections: Truth as a property versus truth as an object, and: The ontology of truth values.